# Refresh List Of Contacts After Delete With Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi newbie here in AngularJs.

I Want to press an delete button in a contact detail screen.
Directly afterwards, when the delete button has been pressed,
I want to return to the main contact list AND have the contact list refreshed.
(With the just deleted contact removed).

Now for the moment the contact gets removed...but if I go run the function

```
$state.go('contactLijst');
```

It will go back to the main page...but then I still have to refresh the page!

Here is my controller:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("lesAmis")
        .controller("PersoonEditController",
        ["contact","$state",   
         PersoonEditController]);

     function PersoonEditController(contact,people,$state){
         var vm = this;
         vm.people = people;
         vm.contact = contact;

vm.delete = function(){
              var id = vm.contact.id;
              if (id) {
                vm.contact.$delete({id:id}, function(data) {
                 toastr.success("OK, persoon verwijderd <br />" + 
                     data.naam);});

                $state.go('contactLijst');}

         };
```

my app.js

```
.state("persoonEdit", {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: "/personen/edit/:id",
                    templateUrl: "app/contacten/contactEditView.html",
                    controller: "PersoonEditController as vm",
                    resolve:{
                        contactResource: "contactResource",
                        contact: function(contactResource, $stateParams){
                            var id = $stateParams.id;
                            return contactResource.get({id: id}).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
```

button in html:

```
button class="btn btn-default"
                            style="width:70px;" 
                            ng-click="vm.delete()">Verwijder
                    </button>
```

I think i need to refresh my controller. But nothing is working. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, try moving your

```
$state.go('contactLijst');
```

inside the function(data) {} function.

This will redirect you back to your main page only after the remove call finishes executing.  Currently the controller fires off the request to remove Contact, then immediately routes you back to the main page (due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript).

Hope this helps!

Comment: For some reason I can't acces the $state paramater anymore if I do it that way...even giving it as a paramater in that function does not work :( $state is undefined :(

Answer (score 1):

Got it !!
Changed 2 things!

Had this first:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("lesAmis")
        .controller("PersoonEditController",
        ["contact","$state",   
         PersoonEditController]);

     function PersoonEditController(contact,people,$state){
```

But ofcourse I have one parameter to many! The 'people' paramater.

So now it is :

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("lesAmis")
        .controller("PersoonEditController",
        ["contact","$state",   
         PersoonEditController]);

     function PersoonEditController(contact, $state){
```

Now My delete function needed an special command! It is `$state.reload();`

Here my new delete function:

```
  vm.delete = function(){
      var id = vm.contact.id;
      if (id) {
        vm.contact.$delete({id:id}, function(data) {
            $state.reload();
            toastr.success("OK, persoon verwijderd");
            $state.go('contactLijst');});

 }};
```

Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Array splice() method.